# Relationship between $B$ and $H$

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

If I have an unknown permanent magnet and I use gaussmeter to measure the $B$ (magnetic flux density), how can I know $H$ (magnetic field strength)? It is known that ${\bf B}=\mu{\bf H}$, but what $\mu$ should it be, i.e: $\mu$ of air or $\mu$ of the magnet, since we measure $B$ on air closer to the magnet and not inside the magnet?

Comment: A permanent magnet does not have a permeability that you can look up.   The $\mu$ in the relation ${\bf B}=\mu{\bf H}$ is only a material constant that you can look up in a book for linear materials.

Answer (score 2):

You should use magnetic permeability of air.

You can think about the magnetic lines inside and around a magnet in terms of a magnetic circuit. The total magnetomotive force (mmf), produced by the magnet, is divided between the magnet itself and the air around it.

Since the reluctance (magnetic resistance) of the air path is much greater than the reluctance of the magnet, most of the mmf is applied to the air path, making the magnetic field strength, H, in the air much greater than inside the magnet.

It is particularly strong near the ends of the magnet, because the cross-section of the magnetic path there is minimal. This explains why the measured magnetic field, B, at these locations is high, even though they are in the air.